# Council and Technical committee accounts disappeared after runtime update

Tags: runtime-upgrade, governance, council

I am working on Substrate-based node update.

After updating from [polkadot-v0.9.10](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/tree/polkadot-v0.9.10) to [polkadot-v0.9.11](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/tree/polkadot-v0.9.11), Council and Technical committee accounts disappeared from the blockchain state.

Additional info:

1. [Blockchain state before the update](https://s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/secure.notion-static.com/0bc27e05-2f83-4506-96a7-92c1403eb2e1/previous_state_block_3585_to_3588_1667916101728.json?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Content-Sha256=UNSIGNED-PAYLOAD&X-Amz-Credential=AKIAT73L2G45EIPT3X45%2F20221114%2Fus-west-2%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20221114T091447Z&X-Amz-Expires=86400&X-Amz-Signature=b0938aa75d8a34b4f96c3d50af7375c346777980f97034eace4514ca66e856ef&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&response-content-disposition=filename%3D%22previous_state_block_3585_to_3588_1667916101728.json%22&x-id=GetObject), collected with our internal tool.
2. [Blockchain State after the update](https://s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/secure.notion-static.com/1d7fb8dc-55f4-4365-be12-50156c7219d9/previous_state_block_3594_to_3597_1667916155593.json?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Content-Sha256=UNSIGNED-PAYLOAD&X-Amz-Credential=AKIAT73L2G45EIPT3X45%2F20221114%2Fus-west-2%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20221114T091309Z&X-Amz-Expires=86400&X-Amz-Signature=02a64262b65b9f13b44c1ef00cb1f627c9418f4f985e17dd8417b03959b876c1&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&response-content-disposition=filename%3D%22previous_state_block_3594_to_3597_1667916155593.json%22&x-id=GetObject)
3. [Blockchain State diff](https://www.diffchecker.com/hEcdRUtV/)
4. Note that not only Council and Technical committee accounts disappeared but also some fields of  proposalsData has been renamed.
5. [Link](https://github.com/Cerebellum-Network/pos-network-node/pull/161) to my PR with the update. Basically it’s pretty match the same as the original polkadot-v0.9.11 branch.
6. I’ve сompared v0.9.10 and v0.9.11 tags in Polkadot repo and found a relevant [PR](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/pull/3511)
7. Haven’t found anything relevant between [v0.9.10 and v0.9.11](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/compare/polkadot-v0.9.10...polkadot-v0.9.11) in Substrate repo.
8. Found several migrations in v0.9.11 for `staking`, `contracts`, `frame_system` `vesting` but it doesn’t seems like it could affect the governance.

Any ideas:

1. Why Council and Technical committee accounts could disappear?
2. How can I fix the disappearance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You missed this one.

https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/pull/9115

Please check the `v0.9.10...v0.9.11` carefully.

You could click the file changes and search `frame/collective`.

Comment: Thank you a lot!
Adding the migrations as it was done in Polkadot has solved the issue.